In apache ignite configuration, can I set up an allow-list of IPs?
I have set up Apache Ignite using the TcpDiscoverySpi. This creates a local port that the server listens to for Apache Ignite traffic.
I would like to only accept connections from trusted servers, a small set of IP addresses.
I don't want to enable authentication. I just want to make sure no other servers can connect to my port except ones from my trusted IP addresses.
